# Upload File from jQuery AJAX POST

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to a server in C#. I'm not sure how else I can explain this, but to say how I do this already using jQuery/PHP.

Currently, using jQuery/PHP, I can easily make my AJAX call and send the uploaded file to my PHP code for processing. In PHP, I can use `$_FILE['postedFileName']` to grab the file from the AJAX call and upload it somewhere on my server.

How can I accomplish this same exact thing, except instead of PHP, I need to do the uploading via C#? Can I use `Request.Params["FILE_NAME"]` in some way to grab it from the AJAX call?

Comment: There are many ways to do this but I would sugest you look at Web API, I also sugest you do some research, try something out and then if you get stuck post back with any problems you might have.

Comment: Look at [Request.Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already sending it successfully in PHP, you can get access to the same variable in C# by referring to the HttpContext.Current.Request.Files variable.

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["postedFileName"]`

will give you access to a HttpPostedFile object, which allows you to access the InputStream, FileName, ContentType, and other properties.